# How can I implement React Hook Form with Radix UI Select?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, radix-ui

I'm using the radix ui primitive Select, but i don't know how to integrate it with React Hook Form. I've tried putting the register in the Select.Root tag but it didn't work.

I'm also using Styled Components so all the Select tags are used like <S.Something/> because i've imported all as S

This is the function that creates the item:

```
const SelectItem = React.forwardRef(({ children, ...props } : any, forwardedRef) => {
        return (
          <S.Item  {...props} ref={forwardedRef}>
            <S.ItemText>{children}</S.ItemText>
            <S.ItemIndicator>
              <S.TriggerIcon src="/form/selector-icon.svg" />
            </S.ItemIndicator>
          </S.Item>
        );
      });
```

Then i create the Select this way:

```
   <S.FormItem key={index}>
      <S.Label htmlFor={index+''}>{question.question}</S.Label>
      <S.Root {...register(`${questionName}`, { required: true })}>
           <S.Trigger id={index+''}>
               <S.Value/>
               <S.Icon>
               <S.TriggerIcon src="/form/selector-icon.svg" />
               </S.Icon>
           </S.Trigger>
       <S.Portal>
          <S.Content>
             <S.SelectorUp>
                 Up
             </S.SelectorUp>
             <S.Viewport>
                  {question.options?.map((option, i) => {
                       return (
                            <SelectItem key={i} value={option}>
                                {option}
                            </SelectItem>
                              )
                  })}          
             </S.Viewport>
             <S.SelectorDown>
                 Down
             </S.SelectorDown>
          </S.Content>
       </S.Portal>
     </S.Root>
  </S.FormItem>
```

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem, but solved it by passing the field.onChange value to onValueChange prop.

I used Controller from the "react-hook-form" library to wrap the Radix Select.

Previously I had it like this

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="currency"
    render={({ field }) => {
      return (
        <Select {...field}>
        ....
        </Select>
      ...
 </Controller>
```

After adding onValueChange prop

```
<Controller
        control={control}
        name="currency"
        render={({ field }) => {
          return (
            <Select onValueChange={field.onChange} {...field}>
            ....
            </Select>
          ...
</Controller>
```

For your code, I think you'll have to wrap the S.Root with the Controller, which will look something like this.

```
<Controller 
       name={`${questionName}`} 
       rules={{required:true}} 
       render={({field})=>{
         <S.Root onValueChange={field.onChange} {...field}>
                  ...
         </S.Root>
    }}></Controller>
```

Comment: The last example needs control={control} like the others. You can get control from `useForm(...)`

Comment: @Cyral good callout, this can also be handled by wrapping the form in `FormProvider`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be the fact that the `Select.Root` component does not pass the `onChange` prop to the `select` HTML element.

In order to fix this, I call the `onChange` function in the `onValueChange` prop. Just passing `onChange` into `onValueChange` did not work for me, instead I pass the `value` and `name` of the input as a plain object:

```js
interface FormSelectProps extends UseFormRegisterReturn {
  children?: ReactNode;
}

export const FormSelect = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, FormSelectProps>(
  ({ name, onChange, required, disabled, children }, ref) => {
    return (
      <Select.Root
        name={name}
        onValueChange={(value) => onChange({ target: { name, value } })}
        required={required}
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        <Select.Trigger ref={ref}>
          <Select.Value />
          <Select.Icon>
            <ChevronDownIcon />
          </Select.Icon>
        </Select.Trigger>

        <Select.Portal>
          <Select.Content>
            <Select.ScrollUpButton>
              <ChevronUpIcon />
            </Select.ScrollUpButton>

            <Select.Viewport>{children}</Select.Viewport>

            <Select.ScrollDownButton>
              <ChevronDownIcon />
            </Select.ScrollDownButton>
          </Select.Content>
        </Select.Portal>
      </Select.Root>
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dropdown to select a category from a few category values. The `Controller` component of the React Hook Form can be used with the Radix UI select component as follows to solve this issue.

```
<Controller
        name="category"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <Select.Root onValueChange={field.onChange}>
            <Select.Trigger placeholder="Expense Category" />
            <Select.Content>
              {categories.map((category) => (
                <Select.Item key={category.id} value={category.value}>
                  {category.label}
                </Select.Item>
              ))}
            </Select.Content>
          </Select.Root>
        )}
      />
```

Here, we're passing the `field.onChange` to the `onValueChange` prop of the `<Select.Root>` component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem(in my case) using `onValueChange={value => setValue('name of the value', value)}` on `<Select.Root>`...

I use it without a `<Controller />`... like this `<Select.Root onValueChange={value => setValue('name of the value', value)}>`